# Avoiding path name to be print with for Loop in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have used for loop for my script as given below:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%G In ('dir /a-d/b/s "%dest%\*.*"') do (
    echo %%G >>%save_file%
)
```

Now when i am running  this job it is printing path name of the files.
I want to save only files name not the path.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo %%~nxG
```

Those modifiers are described in `for /?`

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%G In (
    'dir /a-d/b/s "%dest%*.*"'
) do ( echo %%~nxG >>%save_file% )
```

[Resource for all modifiers.](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)